# How to prove this function has non isolated singularity at the origin?

Tags: complex-analysis

$f(z):= \frac{1}{\sin (\pi/z)}$.
The solution says that $f$ is defined in
$\mathbb{C}\backslash(\{0\}\cup\{1/n:n\in\mathbb{Z}\backslash\{0\}\}) $ (which I understand)
It then goes on to say that $f$ has isolated singularities at $1/n$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}\backslash\{0\}$ but it has a non-isolated singularity at $0$.
I get the intuition behind it having isolated singularities at non-zero points and why it has a non-isolated singularity at the origin, but I'm unsure how this would be proved.

Answer (score 0):

Zero is not isolated singularities of this function since every point $z_n =\frac{1}{n}$ is singular and $z_n\to 0.$